Proof of the fact that an open ball is indeed an open set.
The definition given for an open set is:
A set $U\subset X$ of a metric space $(X,d)$ is open if $\forall p\in U$ there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ such that all points $q$ with $d(q,p)< \varepsilon$ lies inside $U$.
An open ball $B_r(p)$ is the set of points $q$ such that $d(q,p)<r$.
My proof is as follows.
For any point $p$ inside $B_r(p_0)$ we have $d(p,p_0)=r_1<r$. Let $q\in X$ be such that $d(q,p)<r-r_1$. Therefore all points $q$ are such that $d(q,p)+r_1=d(q,p)+d(p,p_0)<r$. By triangle inequality $d(q,p_0)<r$ and we are done. My problem with this proof is that it presupposes that there are $q$ in $X$ with the condition $d(q,p)<r-r_1$. Should we not have to prove that there exists such a $q$? Please clarify. Thank you

You want to prove the relation for any $q\in B_{r-r_1}(p)$. If there is no such $q$, there is nothing to prove. But since $r > r_1$, the ball around $p$ you described is non-empty, so there are actual points $q$ that fulfill the relation.

How is it that the case in which there is no such $q$ we got nothing to prove? Are we supposing that an empty set is also open?

If there's no $q$ it's vacuosly true.

Still did not understand. If there is no $q$ then would there be no open ball at p?

Well there is always at least one point in $B_{r-r_1}(p)$, namely $p$. It there are no other points, you trivially have a ball around $p$, namely $B_{r-r_1}(p)={p}$, which is fully enclosed in the bigger $B_r(p_0)$ so you are done.
